# Git log: get list of files changed by a user since a given date, with number of lines and commit message

Tags: windows, git, logging

I'm interested in knowing the work done by a particular author in a branch since a specific date. I would like to know what files have been modified, the number of lines added/removed and the commit message. The following command is close to what I want but I still need commit message and date:

```
git log --author"someone" --no-merges --since'2015/11/01' --pretty:tformat: --numstat
```

The output is like this:

```
0       16      Project/main.cpp
16      0       Project/bar.json
1       1       Project/foo.cpp

1       1      Project/main.cpp
```

And I would like something like this:

```
0       16      Project/main.cpp       Changed main            2015/11/02
16      0       Project/bar.json       Changed bar             2015/11/02
1       1       Project/foo.cpp        Changed bar             2015/11/02

1       1       Project/main.cpp       Done something to main  2015/11/01
```

Because my end goal is to group by file and sort changes by date, including the commit message, like:

```
2015/11/01   Project/main.cpp    Dome something to main.   1   1 
2015/11/02   Project/main.cpp    Changed main.             0   16 
2015/11/02   Project/bar.json    Changed bar.              16  0 
2015/11/01   Project/foo.cpp     Changed bar.              1   1
```

Note how changes to main.cpp appear together and are sorted by date.

How can I achieve this with git? I'm running under windows and I don't have tools like gawk but I could use PowerShell if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> and I don't have tools like gawk

That's self-defeating.  [Get the real git distribution](https://git-scm.com/download). git's a tool for your toolkit, a major part, but still, part.  Nobody sane's going to duplicate and then have to maintain separate implementations of nontrivial fundamentals.

Then it's

```
git log --pretty=%ci%x09%s --numstat $your $parms $here | awk -F $'\t' '
     NF == 2   { date=$1; subject=$2; next }
     NF == 3   { print date,$0,subject }
' | sort -k6,6 -Vk1,2
```

With powershell you keep bumping up against limits like this.  Maybe it's just ignorance on my part, I've done googling before for decent tools and found none, that's my limit there.